# jQuery - making sure content is loaded before it's faded in?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Nick Craver really helped me out alot with this code in this thread
[jQuery - Can someone help stitching jQuery code with .ajaxComplete()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2743443/jquery-can-someone-help-stitching-jquery-code-with-ajaxcomplete/2743791#2743791)

And it is working. But I notice that there's a small delay after I've clicked a link and before the content is actually loaded. It's not very intense content that's loaded either so I think it's got something to do with the order which things happen in the script.

The original code looks like this:

```
$('.dynload').live('click',
 function(){

 var toLoad = $(this).attr('href')+' #content';
 $('#content').fadeOut('fast',loadContent);
 $('#ajaxloader').fadeIn('normal'); 

 function loadContent() {
     $('#content').load(toLoad,'',showNewContent())
 }
 function showNewContent() {
    $('#content').fadeIn('fast',hideLoader());
    //Cufon.replace('h1, h2, h3, h4, .menuwrapper', { fontFamily: 
'advent'}); 
 }
 function hideLoader() {
     $('#ajaxloader').fadeOut('normal');
 }

 return false;

 });
```

The new code looks like this:

```
$(function() {
  $('.dynload').live('click', function(){
    $('#ajaxloader').fadeIn('fast');
    $('#ajaxloaderfridge').fadeIn('fast');
    var href = this.href + ' #content';

    $('#content').fadeOut('fast',function() {
      $(this).load(href,'', function(data) {
        createMenus();
        $('#ajaxloader').fadeOut('fast');
        $('#ajaxloaderfridge').fadeOut('fast');
        $('#content').fadeIn('fast');
        Cufon.replace('h1, h2, h3, h4, .menuwrapper', { fontFamily: 'advent'});
      });
    }); 
    return false;
  });
});
$(createMenus);

function createMenus() {
  $('#kontrollpanel .slidepanels').kwicks({
     min : 42,
     spacing : 3,
     isVertical : true,
     sticky : true,
     event : 'click'
  });                    
}
```

In the original code, #content is faded out, then the function "loadContent" is started.
Which is basically what is happening in the new script as well isn't it?
And when I was using the old code, the content just faded out and faded in really fast and smooth and with no small pause delay before the content arrived.

Comment: Could I trouble you for a concise statement of what it is exactly that you want to to happen?

Comment: I'm getting 404s for `/img/Footer.png`, `/img/sprite_tints1.png` and `/img/testGB.jpg`, this is going to cause some browser delay, can you fix or remove these images?

Comment: I Nick :)
Thanks for making me clear of these issues :) I've fixed them up now (this is my fool proof preloader for images :p)

However, it doesn't look like it had anything to do with my issue though. I did however notice something with mattbasta's reply.

Edit: This isn't really a huge problem, just a little annoying :)

Comment: @GlenCrawford - Previously, the whole animation of the content fading out and fading out seemed to be alot faster. It's basically just that. And that it looks a little weird, but I'll just going to try to tweak stuff myself :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a faster load, change your click handler to this:

```
$('.dynload').die('click').live('click', function(){
  $('#ajaxloader, #ajaxloaderfridge').fadeIn('fast');
  var href = this.href + ' #content';
  $('#content').fadeOut('fast').load(href, function(data) {
    createMenus();
    $('#ajaxloader, #ajaxloaderfridge').fadeOut('fast');
    $(this).stop().fadeTo('fast', 1);
    Cufon.replace('h1, h2, h3, h4, .menuwrapper', { fontFamily: 'advent'});
  }); 
  return false;
});
```

This triggers loading of the content immediately, not waiting for the fade to finish.  This means you're content is loading **200ms faster**, if it loads before the fadeOut finishes, no problem, it stops the fade and starts fading back in.

Comment: Haha, now it's EXACTLY as is was before, but now with Cufon and the slidemenu working as well! :D

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATED:**

```
$('#content').fadeOut('fast',function() {
      $(this).load(href,'', function(data) {
        createMenus();
        $('#ajaxloader,#ajaxloaderfridge').hide();
       // $('#ajaxloaderfridge').fadeOut('fast');
        $('#content').fadeIn('fast');
        Cufon.replace('h1, h2, h3, h4, .menuwrapper', { fontFamily: 'advent'});
      });
   });
```

OR try this:

```
$('#content').fadeOut('fast',function() {
  $(this).load(href, '', function(data) {
        createMenus();
        $('#ajaxloader,#ajaxloaderfridge').hide();
        Cufon.replace('h1, h2, h3, h4, .menuwrapper', {
            fontFamily: 'advent'
        });
    });
}).fadeIn('fast');
```

Comment: This changes nothing actually. I get what your code is doing, but I don't think that's the source of the problem really.

Comment: What are you really doing here? I can't really see any real difference. I see you do a .hide() there. But that one isn't really a problem. That's just a loader animation in a separate div. It's the #content that should be hidden and then faded in. Is this what is doing it? FadeOut should be replaced with hide?

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your original code is this:

```
$('#content').load(toLoad,'',showNewContent())
```

You're actually calling `showNewContent` right then and there. You want to pass it as a callback. It should look like:

```
$('#content').load(toLoad,'',showNewContent)
```

Same with:

```
$('#content').fadeIn('fast',hideLoader());
```

should be:

```
$('#content').fadeIn('fast',hideLoader);
```

Comment: Ah, ok so I tried going back to the first original code and removed the () from the back of those lines. And this very same problem (the small pause delay) happened. So, I just have to live with it? That's just how it works? I can try a different animation I suppose.